# How to change image on selection of dropdownlist item

Tags: html, css

I am making one Html application. I have number of images in my folder.I want to call all that images in my html application and i want to change images on selection of each item, just like as suppose i have dropdown list which contains 4 flower name and also i am using one image tag.I want to change each image on selection of each flower item how is it possible. Pls help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just answered on the same question.

Using jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402428/working-with-dropdownlist-box-in-html-for-changing-of-image/7402565#7402565

Search please before asking.

Comment: i don't have any idea about jquery.So can we solve this query by use of javascript if yes then pls help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example, on a selection change event, `img#preview` has its `src` attribute set to current selection `value`.

```html
<select onchange="document.getElementById('preview').src = this.value">
  <option selected disabled>Pick a flower...</option>
  <option value="https://i.imgur.com/uAhjMNd.jpeg">Flower 1</option>
  <option value="https://i.imgur.com/UBvQ5Zq.jpeg">Flower 2</option>
  <option value="https://i.imgur.com/b6XaNB3.gif">Flower 3</option>
</select>
<br>
<img id="preview" height="200px">
```

Comment: great,and it is working . Thanks for your help and can you suggest me which is a good site other than w3schools.com for learing jquery.

Answer (score 0):

if you have items with class "myitem" end these items are enumerated by a "id" tag, selected item has an additional class "selected" and your image has class "myImage" you can do this with javascript and jquery:

```
$('.myitem').each( function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass('selected'))
  {
     $('.myImage').attr('src') = 'path-to-images/image'+$(this).attr('id')+'.jpg';
  }
});
```