# select change image and link

Tags: javascript, select

I am trying to change 2 things, a link and an image, when the user selects an `<option>` in a `<select>` element.

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById('pagelink').href = this.link; document.getElementById('image').src = this.value">
    <option link="test.html" value="selectedimage.png">Text</option>
    <option>Another option</option>
</select>
<a id="pagelink"></a>
<img id="image" src="temp.png"/>
```

I adapted this technique from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7411832/2860084)

As you can see, the main problem is that 'link' is a completely made up thing that doesn't work, and as such the link always defaults to "undefined". Unfortunately, I can't have two 'value''s and using 'label' doesn't work.

You might be able to tell that I really don't know a lot about JavaScript. Is there an alternative to 'value' I can use, or a way to define a new, similar element?

Comment: I'll just leave [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) here

Comment: Do you want to always use the value set as the value attribute of the selected option in the select list?

Comment: You should use data attributes and not make your html invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Use `data-link` instead of just `link`, its a convention to use `data-`. You can use [**.getAttribute()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) to retrieve the info inside `data-link`.

HTML

```
<select id="selector">
    <option data-link="test.html" value="selectedimage.png">Text</option>
    <option data-link="test2.html" value="selectedimage2.png">Text2</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('selector').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById('pagelink').href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-link');
    document.getElementById('image').src = this.value
}
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3wzHz/1/)

I also removed your inline code and gave a id `#selector` to the select. Like this you can have javascript on right place and not in the middle of html.

Comment: +1 HTML 5 supports custom data attributes as long as they start with data :)

Comment: More than convention to be more clear, `data-*` is a valid attribute `link` is not.

Comment: @Chad, true. Trying to explain why it sounded like its optional. I corrected.

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/oHadIhu/1/edit)

```
<select id="select">
   <option value="link1,scr1">Text 1</option>
   <option value="link2,scr2">Text 2</option>
</select>
  <br>
<a id="pagelink" href="#">link</a>
<img id="image" src="temp.png"/>
```

```
var d = document,
    $sel = d.getElementById('select'),
    $plk = d.getElementById('pagelink'),
    $img = d.getElementById('image');

$sel.onchange = function(){
  var val = this.value.split(',');
  alert(val[0]+' '+val[1]);
  // $plk.href = val[0];
  // $img.src  = val[1];
};
```

Comment: +1 valid option that I have used many times before using data-* attributes.