# Change image for each Monument which i have selected from dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

Monuments
  
  
    
      Select city
    
    
      Select Monuments

```
<select class="drop" name="chapter" id="chapter" style="display: none; float: right; margin-right: 300px">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Please select topic first</option>
</select>
```

Next
    
    
  
  
  SUBMIT

Comment: Not exactly sure what your question is, but from what I gather from the title, look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7411832/2557342

Answer (score 0):

Your question came missing information, see if that's what you want to do with your code:

I put random image links for the example to work

```js
// Definir um objeto com as imagens correspondentes aos monumentos
const monumentImages = {
  monument1: "https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg",
  monument2: "https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg",
  monument3: "https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg"
};

// Obter o menu suspenso e a imagem do monumento
const chapterSelect = document.getElementById("chapter");
const monumentImage = document.getElementById("monument-image");

// Adicionar um evento 'change' ao menu suspenso
chapterSelect.addEventListener("change", function() {
  // Obter o valor selecionado do menu suspenso
  const selectedMonument = this.value;
  
  // Verificar se o valor selecionado corresponde a uma imagem de monumento existente
  if (monumentImages.hasOwnProperty(selectedMonument)) {
    // Definir o atributo 'src' da imagem do monumento com o caminho da imagem correspondente
    monumentImage.src = monumentImages[selectedMonument];
  } else {
    // Se o valor selecionado não corresponder a uma imagem de monumento existente, definir a imagem padrão
    monumentImage.src = "default-image.jpg";
  }
});
```

```css
/* Estilizar o menu suspenso */
.drop {

  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

/* Estilizar a imagem do monumento */
#monument-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

#chapter {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<select class="drop" name="chapter" id="chapter">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Please select topic first</option>
  <option value="monument1">Monument 1</option>
  <option value="monument2">Monument 2</option>
  <option value="monument3">Monument 3</option>
</select>

<img id="monument-image" src="" alt="">
```

Comment: but i want two dropdowns 2nd one depend on 1st after submitting it image and text visible for each